# Set timeout for notifications.notify FireFox Addon SDK

Tags: firefox-addon

Please help me with Notification in my Firefox add-on.

```
var notifications = require("sdk/notifications");
function showNotifcation(title, text) {
    notifications.notify({
        iconURL: data.url("img/icon.png"),
        title: title,
        text: text
    });
    setTimeout(notifications.close(), 1000);
}
```

Not work.

Comment: "Not work." is not a good enough explanation of your issue.

Comment: What doesn't work, what errors do you get? Please explain the problem to us so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We want to help you. However, you have not provided enough information for us to be able to do so. Right now we have to guess at what you are wanting to happen and what you are experiencing as the problem. Given that notifications are OS dependent, we will also need to know the OS you are using and the version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information from you it is not possible to be sure as to what your problem/issue is.

However, a brief look at the [`sdk/notifications` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications), and source code, indicates that you are attempting to use a non-existent method: `notifications.close()`.  There is no such method in `sdk/notifications`.

One possible reason for your attempt to use this method is that you are conflating the [Web Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API), [more detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification), with the Add-on SDK [`sdk/notifications`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications).

The Add-on SDK, `sdk/notifications`, has no way for you to programmatically close the notification from your code. Thus, there is no way for you to set a timeout for the notification using this interface. However, in some operating systems/windowing systems there is already a default timeout for these notifications.

You will need to either display a panel on your own, or use the chrome interfaces described in [User Notifications and Alerts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/User_Notifications_and_Alerts).

In addition, it would be unusual for you to be able to just call `setTimeout()`. That will, under most contexts, not be defined.  You would normally need to use [`sdk/timers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/timers) with:

```
var { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");
```

In some contexts, you might be able to use [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), when `window` is appropriately defined (which you will probably have to set yourself).

Modifying the code from my answer to [Prevent XUL notificationBox from closing when button is hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35892102/prevent-xul-notificationbox-from-closing-when-button-is-hit/35909233#35909233) (if you want buttons, that answer will show you how to do it), and other answers of mine: Something along the lines of what I believe you desire would be (code for the timeout is at the bottom):

```
function showNotificationBox(text) {
    //Create some common variables if they do not exist.
    if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
        //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on:
        //* Add-on SDK:
        var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
        //*/
        /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
        var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                             .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                             .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
        //*/
    }
    if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
        var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
    }
    let notifyBox = gBrowser.getNotificationBox();
    //appendNotification( label , value , image (URL) , priority , buttons, eventCallback )
    let theNotification = notifyBox.appendNotification(text, "Test notification unique ID",
                                           "chrome://browser/content/aboutRobots-icon.png",
                                           notifyBox.PRIORITY_INFO_HIGH, [], null);
    //* Add-on SDK:
    var { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");
    setTimeout(theNotification.close(), 10000);
    //*/
    /* Overlay and bootstrap:
    let timerCallback = {
        notify:function notify() {theNotification.close(); }
    }
    let closeNotificationTimer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"]
                                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);
    closeNotificationTimer.initWithCallback(timerCallback,10000,
                                            Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
    //*/
}
```

Note: I changed the timeout to 10 seconds from the 1 second which is in the code in your question. One second is a unreasonable amount of time to expect to show anything which you actually desire the user to see and understand.

The above implements the user notification in a [notificationBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/notificationbox).  As such it shows up within the Firefox window:
[image: A notificationBox]

It is also possible to use the [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService) which is what `sdk/notifications` uses. This will normally display an alert box in the bottom right of the screen, potentially outside of the Firefox window (see image on [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService) for example).  The notification may show up elsewhere depending on how you have your windowing system set up (this is OS dependent). However, [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService) did not have a method to clear the notification, or set a timeout.  However, [the interface definition](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/alerts/nsIAlertsService.idl) does show that a `closeAlert()` method does exist.  The source code for the `sdk/notifications` does not expose this to the Add-on SDK.  Thus, you would need to use the chrome interfaces. I have updated the documentation to show `closeAlert()`.

Such as (some code taken and modified from [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService)):

```
//* Add-on SDK:
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
//*/
/* Overlay and bootstrap:
const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;
//*/
function showNotifcation(title, text) {
    var alertsService = Cc["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIAlertsService);
    try {
        //The second use of title is the alert name.
        alertsService.showAlertNotification(icon, title, text, false, "", null, title);
    } catch (e) {
        // This can fail on Mac OS X
    }
    //* Add-on SDK:
    var { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");
    setTimeout(alertsService.closeAlert(title), 10000);
    //*/
    /* Overlay and bootstrap:
    let alertTimerCallback = {
        notify:function notify() {alertsService.closeAlert(title); }
    }
    let closeAlertTimer = Cc["@mozilla.org/timer;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces
                                                                              .nsITimer);
    closeAlertTimer.initWithCallback(alertTimerCallback,10000,Ci.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
    //*/
}
```

I have only tested the above code with a bootstrapped/restartless Firefox add-on.  Thus, the Add-on SDK code may be slightly off.